# How to customize webhook port in openshift 4.5

Tags: openshift, webhooks

Creating a buildconfig and running `oc set triggers bc <my_app> --from-github` creates a webhook for me. However the port is on a non standard one. This causes issues for us since our internal github instance can only connect to e.g. 443 because of a company firewall.

So this leads me to the question, where is this configured? How can I decide which port to use?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to 6443? That's the API server port, and from everything I've found, OpenShift does not currently support changing/configuring this port number.

Comment: Definitive answer (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4665121), not supported but can be worked around in certain environments